# Record And Play Voice in Separate Class (Swift3)

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I used many codes that was for record an play the voice, but most of them are not in swift3 and they don't work in my app.

[This](https://github.com/genedelisa/AVFoundationRecorder) code works, but I want to create a separate class from the viewcontroller that do recording an playing voices. Also the mentioned github code is complex an I'm searching for a simplified code.

**Update:**

After recording, when I check existence of the recorded file, the file doesn't exist, and it raises EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on appDelegate.

What's wrong?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to record audio by wirting line

```
let isRec = AudioManager.shared.record(fileName: "rec")
```

if isRec returned true then recording is happening else not.
To finish recording use : `let recordedURL = AudioManager.shared.finishRecording()`

To play recorded file send above url to `setupUpPlayer()` function in manager class

Not to forget to use extension code snippets give below the code snippet which are delegate functions of `AVAudioRecorder` and `AVAudioPlayer`

```
import Foundation

import AVFoundation

class AudioManager: NSObject {

static let shared = AudioManager()

var recordingSession: AVAudioSession?
var recorder: AVAudioRecorder?
var meterTimer: Timer?
var recorderApc0: Float = 0
var recorderPeak0: Float = 0
//PLayer
var player: AVAudioPlayer?
var savedFileURL: URL?

func setup() {
    recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try recordingSession?.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
        try recordingSession?.setActive(true)
        recordingSession?.requestRecordPermission({ (allowed) in
            if allowed {
                print("Mic Authorised")
            } else {
                print("Mic not Authorised")
            }
        })
    } catch {
        print("Failed to set Category", error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func record(fileName: String) -> Bool {
    setup()
    let url = getUserPath().appendingPathComponent(fileName + ".m4a")
    let audioURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: url.path)
    let recordSettings: [String: Any] = [AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
                                         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue,
                                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                                         AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0]
    do {
        recorder = try AVAudioRecorder.init(url: audioURL, settings: recordSettings)
        recorder?.delegate = self
        recorder?.isMeteringEnabled = true
        recorder?.prepareToRecord()
        recorder?.record()
        self.meterTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { (timer: Timer) in
            //Update Recording Meter Values so we can track voice loudness
            if let recorder = self.recorder {
                recorder.updateMeters()
                self.recorderApc0 = recorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0)
                self.recorderPeak0 = recorder.peakPower(forChannel: 0)
            }
        })
        savedFileURL = url
        print("Recording")
        return true
    } catch {
        print("Error Handling", error.localizedDescription)
        return false
    }
}

func getUserPath() -> URL {
    return FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
}

func finishRecording() -> String {
    recorder?.stop()
    self.meterTimer?.invalidate()
    var fileURL: String?
    if let url: URL = recorder?.url {
        fileURL = String(describing: url)
    }
    return /fileURL
}
//Player
func setupPlayer(_ url: URL) {
    do {
        try player = AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: url)
    } catch {
        print("Error1", error.localizedDescription)
    }
    player?.prepareToPlay()
    player?.play()
    player?.volume = 1.0
    player?.delegate = self
}
}
```

---

```
    //MARK:- Audio Recorder Delegate

    extension AudioManager: AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {

        print("AudioManager Finish Recording")

    }
    func audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, error: Error?) {
        print("Encoding Error", /error?.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

---

```
    //MARK:- Audio Player Delegates

    extension AudioManager: AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

       func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, 
   successfully flag: Bool) {

           player.stop()

           print("Finish Playing")

       }

       func audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, 
    error: Error?) {

            print(/error?.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks For the answer really helped me out

Comment: I use this to play recorded file:                    let path = URL(string: AudioManager.shared.getUserPath().absoluteURL.description + "rec.m4a" )!
        AudioManager.shared.setupPlayer(path)