# How can i update my ViewController UI using this extension delegate in another class

Tags: swift, class, delegates, avfoundation

I'm using a class called `AudioManager` you can find it as an answer to this question [here](http://vhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213081/record-and-play-voice-in-separate-class-swift3/44215084#44215084https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213081/record-and-play-voice-in-separate-class-swift3/44215084#44215084).

It has the delegate method `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` as an extension to the `AudioManager` class.

Is there a way to use this or override these delegate methods in my viewcontroller to be able to change properties in my UI.
This is the extension:

```
extension AudioManager: AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

   func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, 
 successfully flag: Bool) {

       player.stop()

       print("Finish Playing")

   }

   func audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, 
error: Error?) {

        print(/error?.localizedDescription)

    }

}
```

This is my viewcontroller play button code:

```
@IBAction func playButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if AudioManager.shared.player == nil {
        if recordFilePath != nil {
            AudioManager.shared.setupPlayer(URL(string:recordFilePath)!)
        }
    }

    if playButtonIsChecked {
        playButtonIsChecked = false
        AudioManager.shared.player?.play()
        playRecordButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pauseProfileButton"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        playRecordButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "editProfilePlay"), for: .normal)
        playButtonIsChecked = true
        AudioManager.shared.player?.stop()

    }
```

The code above is fine and when i call `player?.stop()` the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` method is being called from the `AudioManager` class but when the audio file comes to an end and stops without me calling `player?.stop` the button background image is not changed ofcourse.

How can i use this delegate method in my viewcontroller and know when my audio file had come to an end and stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AudioManager class you could implement a callback (closure) like:

`var isAudioStopped: ((Bool) -> Void)?`

And you can call it in your extension, in the delegate method:

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer,
```

successfully flag: Bool) {

```
   player.stop()
   isAudioStopped?(true)

   print("Finish Playing")
```

}

Then in your ViewController method:

```
AudioManager.shared.isAudioStopped = {
    [weak self] completion in 
    // if completion the audio is stopped 
}
```

Comment: How will the AudioManager.shared.isAudioStopped be called? It has to be called by itself like the delegate methods of the AVFoundation. As soon as the audio file comes to an end it is called. Where will i call this closure? I call it every 1 sec with a timer to know if the audio has ended in my viewcontroller? :\

Comment: Or maybe add some kind of observer to the variable?

Comment: When the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying method is called your closure is called too with isAudioStopped?(true), then in your ViewController, for example in view did load, you can put the AudioManager.shared.isAudioStopped and get the callback when the audio finish playing. There you can update your button UI

Comment: Yes but i dont want to put the closure in view did load because view did load will already be called once in the life time of the viewcontroller. So when i click play button i will never know if the audio stopped because the closure is in the viewdidload that has already been called.

Comment: Sure, but it’s a callback so if the view did load has already been called doesn’t matter. You will receive the update.

Comment: A closure can capture constants and variables from the surrounding context in which it’s defined. The closure can then refer to and modify the values of those constants and variables from within its body even if the original scope that defined the constants and variables no longer exists.